# How do I pass list results from stored procedure into ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Hi I have below stored procedure :

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspApp_SelectListAutomation]

           @id int,
          @UserID int

            AS
          BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT Automation_notes, Automation_recepientEmail, Automation_frequency
FROM Appmarket_AutomatedReports
WHERE UserID = @UserID AND id = @id
END
```

And I am calling this strored procedure in my index action like this :

```
    var listautomation = orderdata.uspApp_SelectListAutomation(id, userid).ToList();
     ViewData["listresults"] = listautomation;
```

Now I need to pass this into my view and have to display **Automation_notes**, **Automation_recepientEmail** and **Automation_frequency**.

Below is my static code i have written :

```
 <li style="border-left: 2px solid red;"><a href="Index/1">
            <div class="col-14">
                   <h5>
                   **Automation Notes**
                       </h5>
                 <div class="stats">
        ( RECIPIENT: **Automation_recepientEmail** | EVERY **Automation_frequency** | EXPIRES: 19 January 2025 )
                       </div>
                    </div>
                   <div class="clear">
                  </div>
                  </a></li>
```

Can some one tell me how can i make it dynamic by taking results from Stored procedure and pass it in my view ??

Answer (score 1):

You Model and ViewModel should be -

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<DataModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class DataModel
{
    public string Automation_notes { get; set; }
    public string Automation_recepientEmail { get; set; }
    public string Automation_frequency { get; set; }
}
```

Your Controller should be -

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Here you need to get data from SQL and populate the properties accordingly, I mean you need to 
    // call buisness layer method here
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
    model.Items = new List<DataModel>();
    model.Items.Add(new DataModel() { Automation_notes = "Note1", Automation_frequency = "10", Automation_recepientEmail = "Eamil1" });
    model.Items.Add(new DataModel() { Automation_notes = "Note2", Automation_frequency = "20", Automation_recepientEmail = "Eamil2" });

    return View(model);
}
```

You view should be -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.ViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Items) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Label(item.Automation_frequency)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label(item.Automation_notes)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label(item.Automation_recepientEmail)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Output - 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you pass your viewmodel from controller like this

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
        {
            //your code
           return View(listautomation);               
        }
```

then bind it in your view part like this

```
@model ViewModel.ListAutomation
```

Get the value in view like this

```
<input type="text" id="id" value="@Model.ListAutomation " readonly="True"/>
```